# ERROR: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#, visual-studio-2012

I have faced this error: Failed to convert parameter value from a `String` to a `DateTime` when trying to pass multiple selected dates from checkboxlist to my parameter to be used in sql.

I have tried it with other datatypes such as `nvarchar` and it works when I pass multiple selected values to 1 stored procedure parameter and return the select statement using dynamic sql to populate my gridview.

Ps. In my webserver i'm displaying in checkboxlist as e.g `31-Aug-2013`, using `DATE.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}";`. In my sql database, it is displayed as e.g `2013-08-31`.

During debugging selectedDATE do read it as e.g `2013-08-31`. however there is error at da.Fill(ds); line

ASPX.CS

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DATE.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConn))
        {
            try //Call stored procedure
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spddl, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    DATE.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    DATE.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["DATE"].ToString();
                    DATE.DataBind();



                }
                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    Bind();
                }    

            }

            catch (Exception i)
            {
                bool exception = true;
                if (exception == true)
                {
                    //txtMessage.Text += e.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void Bind()
   {
           using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConn))
       {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spretrieve, conn))
           {
                 String selectedDATE = String.Empty;


                if (DATE.SelectedValue == "All")
                {
                    selectedDATE = "DATE";
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (ListItem item in DATE.Items)
                    {
                        if (item.Selected)
                        {
                            DateTime dtTemp = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Value);
                            selectedDATE += "'" + dtTemp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "',";
                        }
                    }

                    selectedDATE = selectedDATE.Substring(0, selectedDATE.Length - 1);
                }


               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = selectedDATE;


               conn.Open();
               SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
               DataSet ds= new DataSet();
               da.Fill(ds);
               GRIDVIEW.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
               GRIDVIEW.DataBind();

           }
       }
```

SQL

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP]

@param nvarchar(512)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE [COLUMN] IN (' + @param + ')'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to convert date into nvarchar first through your query:

```
Convert(varchar,[date_attribute],106)
```

Comment: Not exactly clear where exactly you would apply this and how it would resolve the issue. Consider elaborating a bit on your suggestion.

Comment: obviously you need to apply this while fetching data through SQL Query that will allow you not to handle the case in your C# code